# Heroku doesn't run build script in Create React App folder

Tags: reactjs, heroku, create-react-app, post-build-event, npm-scripts

I have two Node/Express apps with the exact same folder configuration. Both have a front-end folder `/html` - this contains a create-react-app application.

To deploy each app to Heroku, and build the React front-end part,  I'm using a `heroku-postbuild` hook in my package.json. 
It looks like this:

`"start": "node app.js",
"heroku-postbuild": "cd html && npm install && npm run build "`

The problem is this only works for one of the two apps. For one of them Heroku only does the installing modules part, which it reports as successful, but never runs the build script. You can clearly see this in the messages it sends back.

When I try to run the problematic app it doens't find the `/build/index.html` which would be normally generated by running `npm run build`;

What's more, I used Heroku's console `bash` commands, to navigate to the folder  where these should be on the server and it's completely empty. No node_modules, no build folder, no nothing.

It's inexplicable since the two apps are almost identical, their package.json files are almost identical, and the scripts Heroku runs are identical.

ANY help would be appreciated.

Comment: I imagine that this issue is probably derived from the fact that heroku-postbuild runs after the start command. (i.e. since your start runs first, the build never happens).

Comment: At first run script 'npm run build' which will build your front-end for production mode. Then check it locally with  "start": "node app.js" if everything is fine then deploy it to heroku.